# How to place a matplotlib plot into an html container using mpld3 and flask

Tags: python, matplotlib, flask, mpld3

I am trying to use the mpld3-flask example (https://github.com/nipunreddevil/mpld3-flask) as a template to achieve a certain behavior. What I would like, is to add links on the header bar to different plots, rather than having a radio button query form.

Right now, the example code above, in templates/index.html, makes a container and then populates it with a plot when the user submits a query by clicking the "View Plot" button. That happens in this code, as far as I can tell, in index.html:

```
$("#query").click(function() {  

  $("#loading-div-background").show();
  $("#container").hide();
  var plot_type = $('input:radio[name=plot_type]:checked').val();
  var qu = {"plot_type":plot_type}
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/query",
    data: JSON.stringify(qu),
    success: function (data) {     
     var graph = $("#container");
     graph.html(data);   
     $("#loading-div-background").hide();      
     $("#container").show();
   },
   dataType: "html"
 });
});
```

What I would like instead is to add to the header bar that currently has "Home" in it, and bring up each example plot in a different page. I would route to a different link, and then populate the template html code with the data for the plot, without requiring a user query.

I am a bit of a novice with html and essentially know nothing about JavaScript at this point. My *sense* here is that there is some relatively easy way to use flask + jinja2 to do this, but I haven't been able to figure it out.

I am having some trouble with the sort of unclear namespaces that result from combining all of these languages. I am usually very strict with namespaces in my own python programming (i.e. I never, ever use 'from ____ import *') so this is driving me a little crazy.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After working for a while, I have found a solution that seems to work and achieve the behavior I want. Note that I am using the twitter bootstrap css and javascript packages.

Basically, I make a button group:

```
  <div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="home"> Option 1
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2"> Option 2
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
      <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3"> Option 3
  </label>
```

Then in the javascript from the mpld3-flask example I use:

```
$('.btn-primary').on('click', function(){
  var qu = {"plot_type":$(this).find('input').attr('id')}
  $(this).addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    async:true,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "/query",
    data: JSON.stringify(qu),
    success: function (data) {
     var graph = $("#container");
     graph.html(data);
     $("#container").show();
     },
   dataType: "html"
  });  
});
```

Now I have a radio-button bar, with the currently active plot button set to 'active', which only requires one click on one of the buttons to draw a new plot.

EDIT: After learning more about flask and Jinja2, it is also easy to pass the mpld3-generated html to a a template, but there is a slight gotcha; it looks something like this

In the return of your python routing function:

`return render_template('index.html', plot=mpld3_html)`

Then in the html template you can reference this html with

`{{plot|safe}}`

Hope this helps someone else.